# Guice requireBinding to TypeLiteral throws error

Tags: java, guice

I have the following module, with a requireBinding:

```
public class BillingModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(WalletBilling.class).to(WalletBillingService.class);
        requireBinding(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<Map<String, String>>() {}, ResourceUrls.class));
    }



    @Provides
    String returnUrls(@ResourceUrls Map<String, String> resourceUrls){
        return resourceUrls.get("hello");
    }

}
```

I noticed that when I run the code that instantiates the module I get the following error:

Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

```
1) No implementation for java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String> annotated with interface com.example.helloworld.annotations.ResourceUrls was bound.
  at com.example.helloworld.modules.BillingModule.configure(BillingModule.java:32)

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:435)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:154)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at com.example.helloworld.Main.main(Main.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

I thought by annotating the @Provides method param with @ResourceUrls I have satisfied the binding, but this isn't the case, I'm a noob with Guice so will appreciate some pointers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the map in some way, otherwise guice has no idea where to get it from.  Something like this should work.

```
@Provides
@ResourceUrls Map<String, String> getResourceUrls() {
    ...
    return map;
}
```

Comment: This results in "@ResourceUrls is not applicable to method" I believe BindingAnnotations can only be applied to params not methods..

Comment: @jwesonga, no, it depends on your `@ResourceUrls` definition. It is your annotation, isn't it? Check `@Target` annotation on `@interface ResourceUrls` definition. It must contain `METHOD` in order to be applied to method. BTW, Tavian is absolutely right. How Guice should know which map to inject if you didn't define it anywhere?

Comment: I changed the Target of my annotation and everything is running..I guess my problem is that I looked at this code from an existing codebase and it seems to run just fine without the Provider, so I'm not sure where in the original code the map is being provided..

Comment: It's possible they use a `MapBinder`, which is a very useful tool. https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Multibindings

Comment: @TavianBarnes I dug deeper into the source code and discovered there was a provider with the annotation,I've accepted your answer..